# IndexError: string index out of range – even though the program gives the desired output

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, index-error

I try to write a function 'tokenize' were the input is a list of text lines. I go through all lines, split them into words, accumulate the recognized words and finally return the complete list.

The function 'tokenize' looks like this:

```
def tokenize(lines):
    words = []
    for line in lines:
        start = 0
        while start < len(line):
            while line[start].isspace():
                start = start + 1
            end = start
            if line[start].isalpha():
                while line[end].isalpha():
                    end = end + 1
                word = line[start:end]
                word = word.lower()
                words.append(word)
                start = end
            elif line[start].isdigit():
                while line[end].isdigit():
                    end = end + 1
                word = line[start:end]
                words.append(word)
                start = end
            else:
                word = line[start]
                words.append(word)
                start = start + 1
    return words
```

When I give the input

```
wordfreq.tokenize(['15,    delicious&   Tarts.'])
```

It gives the output

```
['15', ',', 'delicious', '&', 'tarts', '.']
```

This is the desired output, so nothing is wrong with that.

However, when I use the testing script below to make sure that there is no corner cases that the function 'tokenize' missed out;...

```
import io
import sys
import importlib.util

def test(fun,x,y):
    global pass_tests, fail_tests
    if type(x) == tuple:
        z = fun(*x)
    else:
        z = fun(x)
    if y == z:
        pass_tests = pass_tests + 1
    else:
        if type(x) == tuple:
            s = repr(x)
        else:
            s = "("+repr(x)+")"
        print("Condition failed:")
        print("   "+fun.__name__+s+" == "+repr(y))
        print(fun.__name__+" returned/printed:")
        print(str(z))
        fail_tests = fail_tests + 1

def run(src_path=None):
    global pass_tests, fail_tests

    if src_path == None:
        import wordfreq
    else:
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("wordfreq", src_path+"/wordfreq.py")
        wordfreq = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(wordfreq)

    pass_tests = 0
    fail_tests = 0
    fun_count  = 0

    def printTopMost(freq,n):
        saved = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
        wordfreq.printTopMost(freq,n)
        out = sys.stdout.getvalue()
        sys.stdout = saved
        return out

    if hasattr(wordfreq, "tokenize"):
        fun_count = fun_count + 1
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, [], [])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, [""], [])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["   "], [])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["This is a simple sentence"], ["this","is","a","simple","sentence"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["I told you!"], ["i","told","you","!"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["The 10 little chicks"], ["the","10","little","chicks"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["15th anniversary"], ["15","th","anniversary"])
        test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["He is in the room, she said."], ["he","is","in","the","room",",","she","said","."])
    else:
        print("tokenize is not implemented yet!")

    if hasattr(wordfreq, "countWords"):
        fun_count = fun_count + 1
        test(wordfreq.countWords, ([],[]), {})
        test(wordfreq.countWords, (["clean","water"],[]), {"clean":1,"water":1})
        test(wordfreq.countWords, (["clean","water","is","drinkable","water"],[]), {"clean":1,"water":2,"is":1,"drinkable":1})
        test(wordfreq.countWords, (["clean","water","is","drinkable","water"],["is"]), {"clean":1,"water":2,"drinkable":1})
    else:
        print("countWords is not implemented yet!")

    if hasattr(wordfreq, "printTopMost"):
        fun_count = fun_count + 1
        test(printTopMost,({},10),"")
        test(printTopMost,({"horror": 5, "happiness": 15},0),"")
        test(printTopMost,({"C": 3, "python": 5, "haskell": 2, "java": 1},3),"python                  5\nC                       3\nhaskell                 2\n")
    else:
        print("printTopMost is not implemented yet!")

    print(str(pass_tests)+" out of "+str(pass_tests+fail_tests)+" passed.")

    return (fun_count == 3 and fail_tests == 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

... I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py", line 81, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py", line 50, in run
    test(wordfreq.tokenize, ["   "], [])
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/test.py", line 10, in test
    z = fun(x)
  File "/Users/ericjohannesson/Documents/Fristående kurser/DAT455 – Introduktion till programmering med Python/lab1/Laborations/Laboration_1/wordfreq.py", line 44, in tokenize
    while line[start].isspace():
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why does it say that the string index is out of range? I have debugged the 'tokenize' function and it looks fine to me, why does it still complain?

Comment: "This is the desired output, so nothing is wrong with that." Okay; and if you manually use the example test that fails? It will fail, yes? Things that your code does correctly are not interesting when it comes to figuring out where the problems are.

Comment: "I have debugged the 'tokenize' function and it looks fine to me" It's not clear to me what you think "debugging" actually entails. Your **first** step should be to look at *specifically the test case that failed*, and look at the line of code where it failed, and figure out *what must be true* to cause the `IndexError`. Then work backwards and try to explain it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If my input is [] (that is, an empty line), then words = []. Then start == 0 and len(line) == 0. That means that start < len(line) is false, so the function returns []. So there's no problems with empty lines.

Comment: use the debugger to step through the handling of the failed test, just like Karl suggested

Comment: Your line `while line[start].isspace()` does not perform this check. The preceding `start < len(line)` only verifies that there is something, not that there is a valid start.

Comment: " If my input is [] (that is, an empty line)" Your input is not `[]`. Your input is not a list at all; it is a string. The failing input is not an empty string, either. Pay closer attention.

Answer (score 1):

You run into issues with the test code both when the input is a list holding a multiple-space long single string, and when it is a list holding a multi-character single string.
Therefore, extend the `tokenize` function in your `wordfreq`, by both returning early on empty:

```
if not lines or all(x.isspace() for x in lines):
    return words
```

And checking the length of your iterator inside the for-loop:

```
while end != len(line) and line[end].isalpha():
```

Full program, `wordfreq.py`:

```
def tokenize(lines):
    words = []

    if not lines or all(x.isspace() for x in lines):
        return words

    for line in lines:
        start = 0
        while start < len(line):
            while line[start].isspace():
                start += 1
            end = start
            if line[start].isalpha():

                while end != len(line) and line[end].isalpha():
                    end += 1

                words.append(line[start:end].lower())
                start = end
            elif line[start].isdigit():
                while line[end].isdigit():
                    end += 1
                words.append(line[start:end])
                start = end
            else:
                words.append(line[start])
                start += 1
    return words


print(tokenize(['15,    delicious&   Tarts.']))
print(tokenize([]))
print(tokenize([""]))
print(tokenize(["   "]))
print(tokenize(["This is a simple sentence"]))
print(tokenize(["I told you!"]))
print(tokenize(["The 10 little chicks"]))
print(tokenize(["15th anniversary"]))
print(tokenize(["He is in the room, she said."]))
```

Returns:

```
['15', ',', 'delicious', '&', 'tarts', '.']
[]
[]
[]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'simple', 'sentence']
['i', 'told', 'you', '!']
['the', '10', 'little', 'chicks']
['15', 'th', 'anniversary']
['he', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'room', ',', 'she', 'said', '.']
```